# Why is there a white line on my Coffee cup?

Tags: rendering

I'm doing the blenderguru coffee tutorial and I need help. I've[image] finished all the tutorials but there are still some problems. The glass looks weird and there is a white line in the coffee.

Comment: The white line seems to be the edge of the plate under the cup. Its because of the bright light on the edge that can be seen through the cup more then the rest of the material. I found myself I quiet problematic to set the transparency of glass to match the real life materiel, especially when you have multiple glas objects.

Comment: The fuzz on the coffee cup is because of low sampling. You can either turn up your samples, or try to use denoising. The white line could be any number of things, so I recommend you upload your blend file with blend-exchange.com